# SP2013 Checkif a pdf file is signed through a workflow

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, pdf, digital-signature

Here's a scenario. On SharePoint 2013 in a document library, a user uploads a PDF file with signable fields. Then a workflow kicks off to email another user to go in and review that PDF, and then add his/her digital signature if approved.

Is there a way for that workflow (or another one) to check if a digital signature has been added to the PDF file?

> **Extra:** Is it also possible to check for multiple signatures and verify them specifically with specific fields. For example, there's two signature fields, and the workflow needs to tell which field was signed for two different if/else conditions.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear on that. What I meant was that the user approved the document by mannually adding his/her electronic signature into the PDF file (specifically into the signature field that has an editable region). After adding a signature, the user checks in the document back into SharePoint document library. That's all the user has to do; then, the workflow should kick in and scan/search the PDF file for a signature. >**Note:** This isn't an answer but a reply to Nagababu Annamdasu's answer. Since I've just created a stack exchange account, I'm unable to comment on answers since you nee

Answer (score 0):

You said when user approved the document then signature automatically added to PDF. If this is right then following is helpful.

For verifying one digital signature, you should maintain one extra custom column in SP list like **isDigitalSignatureDone** (Yes/No).
By default this value is **NO**.
When user approved the document then set this field value as **YES** through workflow/code.
Based on this field status, Can find signature is added or not to the PDF.

If you want to know multiple signatures you can add multiple columns or you can add a CHOICE field with multi-select options. You can set value for each signature.

Hope this helps you. If this helps to you, up vote this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. You would need to create a custom web service that would check that on the back end and then call that service from the workflow. The amount of effort on the workflow is relatively minimal, but the web service would take some coding effort.